# How to Add a Cert to System.keychain Without SecKeychainCopyDomainDefault

Tags: objective-c, macos, certificate, keychain

As of MacOS 10.10 `SecKeychainCopyDomainDefault` was deprecated. The SecItemAdd key `kSecUseKeychain` is however not deprecated. `kSecUseKeychain` requires a `SecKeychainRef` as a value, but I do not see any non-deprecated way of obtaining one.

I need to add a CA to the System keychain. The following code is a working example when ran as root.

```
SecKeychainRef system;
OSStatus keychainError = SecKeychainCopyDomainDefault(kSecPreferencesDomainSystem, &system);

CFDataRef data = CFDataCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,  nsdataCert.bytes, nsdataCert.length);
SecCertificateRef test = SecCertificateCreateWithData(kCFAllocatorDefault, data);

const void *keys[] = { kSecClass, kSecAttrLabel, kSecValueRef, kSecUseKeychain};
const void *values[] = { kSecClassCertificate , @"Test Certificate", test, system};

CFDictionaryRef query = CFDictionaryCreate(kCFAllocatorDefau1lt, keys, values, 4, NULL, NULL);

int status = SecItemAdd ((CFDictionaryRef)query, NULL);
NSLog(@"status=%d", status);
```

Comment: Any luck finding out how to do this without a deprecated function?